# IOS dev. Tap button, screen does not call a new view

Tags: ios, button, view

Goal: to switch views when you click the button.
What I did:

1. Open a single view application.
2. File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch & Objective -C. Create
   PlayViewController and GMViewController, both subclass
   UIViewController.
3. Went to mainstoryboard and from the object library, I dragged two
   View Controllers, with PLayViewController and GMViewController as
   their STORYBOARD IDs.
4. IN ViewController.h I have these codes:

.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @class PlayViewController;
    @class GMViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) PlayViewController *playViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GMViewController *gmViewController;


- (IBAction)toPlay:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)toGM:(id)sender;

@end
```

Basically, here I created two buttons. one will go to PlayView, the other to GMView.

```
 5. In my ViewCotroller.m, I have these:

 #import "ViewController.h"
 #import "PLayViewController.h"
 #import "GMViewController.h"

 - (IBAction)toPlay:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
PlayViewController *playController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayViewController"];
self.playViewController = playController;


[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view insertSubview: self.playViewController.view atIndex:0];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)toGM:(id)sender {
//still blank, waiting to fix the play button.
```

}

Problem is when I click the play button the screen goes black. Please tell me what I missed. Thanks

Comment: @iPatel Post it as answer, with little explanation  .

Comment: change the index of this line?

Comment: you don't have to remove self.view, if you'll remove self.view all its subviews will be removed as well. So just insert subview or add subview. You can also try to push to next view controller instead of inserting or adding a subview.

Comment: i did try removing the self.view removeFromSuperview, but the result is that when i click the play button no reaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, you are first removing `self.view` and then you are trying to `insertSubview` on `self.view` thats way it is not working for you so change your code with

first insret `self.playViewController.view` to `self.view` and then it remove from super view such like,

```
[self.view insertSubview: self.playViewController.view atIndex:0];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope that my suggestion will be work for you.

Comment: tnx, for the quick reply, but it still goes black.

Comment: @user3266210 : delete `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` and try with `bringSubviewToFront` -- `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.playViewController.view]`